# Reason for subtracting substring()'s endIndex by 1

Tags: java, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why from index is inclusive but end index is exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339158/why-from-index-is-inclusive-but-end-index-is-exclusive)

`substring()` method => `String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Description:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The first
>   integer argument specifies the index of the first character. The
>   second integer argument is the index of the last character - 1.

Take a look at the following code:

```
String anotherPalindrome = "Niagara. O roar again!"; 
String roar = anotherPalindrome.substring(11, 15);
```

Output: `roar`

Now, if the JVM didn't substract `int endIndex` by one, we could just use `substring(11,14)` instead, wouldn't that be much more convenient and less error-prone (human side)? Had you not read the description carefully, you might just ended up scratching your head for half an hour (like I did) when you thought that `endIndex` is just the normal index. What's the reason for the Java language creators to subtract it by one?

Comment: also, substring(int beginIndex, int length) would have made more sense. you know how many chars u are going to extract!!!

Comment: "Beginning inclusive, end exclusive" has been traditional in C-like languages for decades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has several advantages:

```
s.substring(0, s.length())
```

is always correct. Also:

```
s.substring(i, j)
```

The size of resulting string is always `j - i`. More specifically `s.substring(0, j)` will always return `j` characters. Finally this means that if you want to take `n` characters after index `i` you simply say:

```
s.substring(i, i + n)
```

It's also easier to extract suffix of a string (last `n` characters):

```
s.substring(s.length() - n, s.length())
```

For example extracting file extension:

```
s.substring(s.indexOf('.') + 1, s.length())
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as numbering the gaps between letters, not the letters themselves:

```
 N i a g a r a . _ O  _  r  o  a  r  _  a  g  a  i  n  !
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Clearly, `roar` is the substring between `11` and `15`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same question as:

"Why do the arrays in Java start at 0 and not at 1".

Indeed, since the arrays start at 0 you usually write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
```

similarly if you want a substring starting from start and ending at end you would use something like:

```
for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
    //get ar[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

substring seems to be used often together with the indexOf method. In those cases, you can directly use the found index as the endIndex parameter to cut off the string up to a delimiter string. Example:

```
    String text = "filename.ext";

    int pos = text.indexOf(".ext");
    String name = text.substring(0, pos);
    assertEquals("filename", name);
```

In those cases, the `pos` variable already contains the index of the dot, and substring can cut off the string up to the dot.