# Who does substring(startIndex,endIndex) return string from startIndex start till endIndex-1?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    String mySite = "StackOverflow";
    System.out.println(mySite.substring(0, 4));
}
```

What this print is `Stac`
As per my understanding indexing starts from 0.

```
S<-0
t<-1
a<-2
c<-3
k<-4
```

When I specify I need String from index 0 to index 4 i expect `Stack` to be returned but it returns `Stac`.

When I looked at the **substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)** source code it says the following.

```
 * @param      beginIndex   the beginning index, inclusive.
 * @param      endIndex     the ending index, exclusive.
```

Can someone explain what does inclusive and exclusive is meant in this context? Why was it not made more intuitive? Does anyone know any specific reason for such behavior?

Comment: `substring()` doesn't print anything at all. Please fix your title to something meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Inclusive* means that the item at that index will be included.
- *Exclusive* means that the item at that index will **not** be included.

The true reasons for this can only be guessed, unless you can find a comment in source code explaining it (possible), or find and ask the original author(s) (highly unlikely).

One could infer that the reason is because `String`s and `List`s and the like in Java (and nearly all other languages) are 0-indexed (which, from your question, you seem to understand so I'll skip explaining that), but the value of the length of these is always one more than the value of the final index. There are many other examples and instances of excluding the final index of some sort of "substring"/"sublist"/etc. functionality, as this makes it easy to just take the length of your string/list/etc. and pass that as the end index, and then always assume it will be excluded in the underlying implementation of the sub-whatever functionality so that the user doesn't have to always remember to put a `-1` or similar offset if the length is used as the end index.

So really, it's arguably (more) intuitive after you realize the interaction of 0-index vs. length.

There's a good explanation in the accepted answer of [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339158/why-from-index-is-inclusive-but-end-index-is-exclusive) that brings C into the explanation.

Comment: What is unquestionably more intuitive is methods that take a start index and a length instead of a start/end index :)

Comment: @280Z28 Arguably so, but I would think one is more likely to wind up with two indices because of various `indexOf`-style methods (from which length could be calculated), rather than only one index and a length, so presuming that it would make sense to have more start-to-end-index methods than to have start-index-with-length methods. Also, much of this is based on C conventions since Java was loosely based on C, so whether those conventions sensibly apply to Java or not anymore, they're there.

Answer (score 2):

**Inclusive** means that the character at that index will be **included**.
**Exclusive** means that the character at that index will be **excluded**.

Basically, it will include very character *until* – but not including – `endIndex`.

Comment: Any specific reason for such non intuitive behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Inclusive = character is included

Exclusive = character is not included

The reason for this is probably historical convention, but I do not know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

'Intuitive' is in the eye of the beholder.

You will find when you come to write some code that the behaviour is extremely handy. When constructing a substring you usually have the index of the first thing that's in it and either:

1. The desired length, in which case `endIndex` is just `startIndex+length`, or
2. The index of the first character that *isn't* in the desired substring, for example a separator, in which case again it is already the correct value for `endIndex`.

The third case is when you have the index of the last desired character in the substring, in which case `endIndex` should be set to that value plus 1. But this is only one out of three cases (so far).