# Java substring endindex-1

Tags: java, string, substring

I was using `substring` in a project, earlier I was using `endindex` position which was not creating the expected result, later I came to know that java `substring` does `endindex-1`. I found it not useful. So why Java is doing `endindex-1` instead of plain `endindex` ?

My code is as follows.

```
String str = "0123456789";
String parameter1 = str.substring(0,4);
String parameter2 = str.substring(5,8);`
```

Comment: is this related to regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717740/who-does-substringstartindex-endindex-return-string-from-startindex-start-till?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Why is substring() method substring(start index(inclusive), end index (exclusive))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631078/why-is-substring-method-substringstart-indexinclusive-end-index-exclusive)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has a number of advantages, not least that `s.substring(a,b)` has length `b-a`.

Perhaps even more useful is that

```
s.substring(0,n)
```

comes out the same as

```
s.substring(0,k) + s.substring(k,n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc explains why, by having it this way

endIndex-beginIndex = length of the substring

The parameters are therefore defined as

beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.

A use case would be when you do something like

```
int index = 3;
int length = 2;
str.substring(index,index+length);
```

Its just easier to programatically do things when uses the endIndex in the exclusive way

Answer (score 2):

Java always uses the begin parameter as inclusive and the end parameter as exclusive to determine a range.

```
[0:3[ <=> 0, 1, 2
[4:6[ <=> 4, 5
```

you will find this behaviour several time within the API of java:
List,
String,
...

it's defined years ago within the java spec.
and imho this is awesome and very useful.
So with this definition you can make this.

```
String x = "hello world";
String y = x.substring(0, x.length() - 6); // 6 = number of chars for "world" + one space.
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(y);
builder.append(x.subSequence(5, x.length())); // 5 is index of the space cause java index always starts with 0.
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Otherwise you always have to calculate to get the real last char of a String.